# How can I update a row with a Double value using B4A and Jackcess?

Tags: ms-access, basic4android, jackcess

I am creating an MS Access database with B4A (was: basic4android) and Jackcess. Every time I try to save a Double value I get the error

> JavaLangNumberFormatException invalid double : "null".

How can I update the Access field with a Double value using B4A and Jackcess?

```
Private Sub ButtonSaveRecordToDataBase_Click

Dim SaveRecord(4) As String

SaveRecord(0) = contact_code
SaveRecord(1) = record_date
SaveRecord(2) = record_quantity
SaveRecord(3) = record_value

RecordsTable.AddRow(SaveRecord)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `SaveRecord` array is declared `As String`. One of the elements (`record_value`, I presume) contains the *string* `"null"` and Jackcess won't accept that as a Double value. You may need to declare your `SaveRecord` array <strike>`As Variant`</strike> `As Object` so it can contain true `Null` values.

Comment: I convert the string value to double before i use it and the problem continues. Basic4android has no variant data type